# Shared folder in owncloud

Tags: owncloud, cloud-storage

whe you share a folder (named shareFolder) to the user2 and then when you log in as user2 you can see the shareFolder into **"Shared"**  folder in my home, how can I change the name of this folder ?, thanks

Comment: This has nothing to do with programming and is more appropriate for ServerFault or even Web Applications.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a cloud-based storage app and not about programming.

Comment: Even with your edit, this is still off-topic...

Comment: Sorry @esqew, I'm new butI think this is related with php because I have to chnage the code to do that, It's wrong what I'm saying ?

Comment: @godambrosio *because you have to change the code to do that*... just because you have to change the code doesn't make it PHP. You haven't presented any evidence that this is a programming question. Show us some code and what difficulties your having with said code. Otherwise, this just looks like a technical support question.

Comment: Ok, now I understand thanks for that, I have to delete it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ownCloud 7 will get rid of the `shared` folder; instead, shared files are identified with the overlay icon representing “shared with me”. (If users are upgrading, they can continue to use the Shared folder they already have.)

ownCloud 7 will be released on July 23rd 2014. Have a look at this page: http://owncloud.org/seven/